# How to Generate Light in the 10,000K Spectrum?

Tags: power-supply, led, power, light, watts

I need to generate a lot of light with the same spectrum as the sun - 10,000 Kelvin (10000K). I have searched around for hours, however all full spectrum lights available are either 5500K or 6500K - but I need 10000K..

For reference I've searched Amazon for hours but I found nothing. I searched other places and the only such bulbs I found where for cars or fish tanks.

Therefore, I'm interested in learning what technology is available to generate this kind of light spectrum?

I am not asking for specific product recommendations but rather the general category of such products. For example, one person recommended a metal-halide discharge lamp.

Are there any other options?

Comment: Good luck with that. I've stuck to 6500K myself.

Comment: Maybe you could combine the 6500K lights with some ~450nm (royal blue) LED light.

Comment: And I always thought natural daylight has 6500K

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Thanks.. But I don't think this would work as I need to generate more than 5,000 lux of blue light..

Comment: @PlasmaHH - nope people use the term "natural light" at 6500K but the sun produces spectrum closer to 10000K - which is more "blue" than "white"

Comment: The Sun produces light at 5900K. Rayleigh scattering pushes the color of the sky past 15000K.

Comment: @DannyBein: Hm, all astronauts that I talked to said that the sunlight is white... And shouldn't the suns spectrum be mostly near its surface temperature? That would be ~6000K or so...

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Thanks for correction.. I mean the light that reaches the human eye

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: I don't think that it pushes also the color of sunlight to 15000k, does it?

Comment: Unfortunately, recommendations for specific products are off-topic in this forum.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: No, the color of sunlight itself changes very little.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: That probably means he looks for a light source that allows to replicate conditions in the blue hour...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your best bet technology-wise is a metal-halide discharge lamp (which will require a matching ballast). Specific product recommendations are off-topic here, but I suspect this is the right technology for the job.